# Can't close AlertDialog using timer, custom view and Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, android-alertdialog, splash-screen, xamarin

I want to make a splash screen using AlertDialog.Builder, a custom view and a timer.

I'm using Xamarin.Android - i don't have the 'dismiss' method it seems, i can call 'dispose' but the alertDialog view does not close.

Example code below:

```
public class SplashDialog
{
    private readonly AlertDialog.Builder _alert;
    private readonly View _view;


    public SplashDialog(Context context)
    {
        _alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        var layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        _view = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.splash, null);
        _alert.SetView(_view);

    }

    public void Show()
    {
        _alert.Show();

      /*
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            _view.Dispose();
            _alert.Dispose();

        }).Start();
         * */

        new Handler().PostDelayed(() =>
            {
                _view.Dispose();
                _alert.Dispose();

            }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is true `AlertDialog.Builder` doesn't have a `Dismiss()` method, but when you call `_alert.Show()`, it returns an `AlertDialog` instance which has the `Dismiss()` method. You just need keep the instance somewhere and call it when you need it, like this

```
private AlertDialog _dialog;

public void Dismiss()
{
    _dialog.Dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Aaron is right. But you should really be using DialogFragment (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) for displaying modals such as `AlertDialog`s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply. I wrote some code and confirmed it worked!